# Fence against a wall

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the follwoing code. I want to have a wall and a rectangle, but this doesnot look good. I want it to be better, i.e., three dimensional so it looks better. I mean a standing wall. How can I do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\definecolor{brickcolor}{HTML}{F0D8B2}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary {patterns}
\def\wall{ \fill     [fill=brickcolor]  (0,-1) rectangle (8,.5);
           \pattern  [pattern=bricks,pattern color=white] (0,-1) rectangle (8,.5);
          }

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red, very thick, text=black](2,0)--node[above left]{$x$}(2,2)--node[above]{$y$}(6,2)--node[above right]{$x$}(6,0 );
  \wall
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use Ti*k*Z `3d` library for `canvas is...` options. These options let you draw in any plane parallel to the coordinate planes. Then a couple of clips and you have it.

**Update:** I couldn't help it. This needed a duck!!!

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks} % only for the duck, obviously

\definecolor{brickcolor}{HTML}{F0D8B2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,3d view={210}{20}]
% wall
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \clip (-3.99,0) rectangle (3.99,2.5);
  \foreach\y in {0,...,9} \foreach\x in {-8,...,8}
    \fill[brickcolor] ({0.5*\x-0.24-0.25*mod(\y,2)},0.25*\y) rectangle ++ (0.48,0.23);
\end{scope}
% duck
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=1] (1,0) pic[duck/water=blue!50,scale=0.25] {duck};
% fence, x
\foreach\i in {-2,2}
{
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=\i,green!50!black]
    \draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \foreach\x in {-3.8,-3.6,...,1.8}
      \draw (\x,0) --++ (2,2) --++ (2,-2);
  \end{scope}
}
\node[below] at (-2,1) {$x$};
% fence, y
\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=2,green!50!black]
  \draw[thick] (-2,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \clip (-2,0) rectangle (2,2);
  \foreach\x in {-5.8,-5.6,...,1.8}
    \draw (\x,0) --++ (2,2) --++ (2,-2);
\end{scope}
\node[below] at (0,2) {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice drawing +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thanks!!!

Comment: good that you caught dinner

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh no

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, fortunately, ducks have wings.